# How to render clickable urls using react-json-to-table?

Tags: html, json, reactjs, url, html-table

i'm new to coding and i'm building a web app using reactjs. i need to render a widget that contains a table to display data that comes from the back-end in json format. The table will change dynamically over time and will always be different.

I found a library that could work for me :

https://github.com/thehyve/react-json-to-table

It works like wonders, but i can't render clickable urls in the tables.
Someone can help me archieve this?

i have some data like this:

```
{
    "Loaded by": "Jills",
    "Load id": 34,
    "git id": "xxqaygqertqsg98qhpughqer",
    "Analysis Id": "7asdlnagsd98gfaqsgf",
    "Load Date": "July 12, 2018",
    "Data Source": "Study XY123-456",
    "Jira Ticket": "Foo-1",
    "Confluence URL": "http://myserver/wxyz"
  }
```

the my component looks like this:

```
export default class TableWidget  extends BaseWidget {



constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { data } = this.props;
    const data2 = data;


    this.state = {
      data: this.getData(data2)
    };

    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    super.componentWillMount();
    this.props.socket.on(`widget:update:${this.props.jobName}:${this.props.name}`, datas => {
      logger('info', `updating widget: ${this.props.jobName}:${this.props.name}`, datas);
      this.setState({
        data: this.getData(datas.value),
      });
    });
}


getData(data) {

  const demoJson = {
    "Loaded by": "Jills",
    "Load id": 34,
    "git id": "xxqaygqertqsg98qhpughqer",
    "Analysis Id": "7asdlnagsd98gfaqsgf",
    "Load Date": "July 12, 2018",
    "Data Source": "Study XY123-456",
    "Jira Ticket": "Foo-1",
    "Confluence URL": "http://myserver/wxyz"
  };

  if (data == null )
    return demoJson;
  else 
    return data;
}

  static get layout() {
return {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  w: 4,
  h: 3,
  minH: 3,
  maxH: 40,
  minW: 4,
  maxW: 10,
};
  }

  static get className() {
    return 'TableWidget';
}

  handleResize() {
this.chart.reflow();
  }


render() {

    const classList = classNames(...this.classList, 'widget', 'widget__table',);
    return (
      <div className={classList}>
        <h1 className="widget__title">{this.props.title}</h1>
        <JsonToTable json={this.state.data} /> 


            </div>
    );
}

}


 TableWidget.propTypes = {   
title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
```

the table renders fine but i want to be albe to clikc on the "conference url". how can i archieve this?

maybe I could use one of these two libraries?

https://github.com/arqex/react-json-table

or

https://github.com/agracio/ts-react-json-table

thanks for the help and sorry if i made some English or code abominations.

Comment: I just perused the source code for JsonToTable, doesn't look like it exposes a custom render table row function, but the basic gist is you need direct access to table entries so you can add an onClick handler. You'll also need this access so you can extract the URL. In other words, you'll need something else It's just json, iterate over it yourself.